# flowplayer in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flowplayer, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'd like to start a flowplayer instance when a modal window is opened (bootstrap). I have the following code but the player won't start (and doesn't throw an error either):

```
$('#rmTour').on('shown', function() {
    var api = $(".flowplayer:first").data("flowplayer");
    api.play(0);
});
```

The modal id is "rmTour".

Comment: Does your modal id is rmTour ??

Comment: Yes, it is (stupid minimal character length).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still using 2.3.2 which uses "shown". The event gets fired.